# Twillio iOS App, not making calls properly

Tags: ios, twilio

I am experimenting with Twillio for iOS, and going through the quick start tutorial here

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/passing-parameters

Now I setup a heroku account as per the tutorial and so far I am accomplishing everything up until the point where I press dial in the app and make a call to a cell phone that I entered, I get an automated message saying " Welcome to Twillio"
and then in like 3 seconds it hangs up. No Error  messages are logged or anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Assuming you are using the TwiML sample from [the previous step in Twilio Client for iOS the quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/twilio-application), it sounds like your application is behaving as expected.

When using Twilio Client, you need to tell Twilio what to do with the VoIP connection thats being from iOS into Twilio, which you do by setting up a web server that has a URL that returns a set of TwiML "verbs".  In the Quickstart, the TwiML we show includes the `<Say>` verb, which tells Twilio to take text and turn it into the robot voice that you're hearing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Welcome to Twilio</Say>
</Response>
```

Once Twilio finishes executing all of the TwiML verbs you give it, it disconnects the call.

If you want a different experience from whats shown in the Quickstart you can just change the TwiML your server returns.  For example, if you want to have Twilio drop that Client call into a conference you could change the TwiML to:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
         <Conference>Party Time</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

If you want Twilio to dial a PSTN number (like making a call to a cell phone), you would use the `<Dial>` verb with the `<Number>` noun:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
         <Number>+15555555555</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This document I posted doesn;t talk about the <say>, it clearly states that I can call a cell phone from the app, that is the issue, I cannot make a call. https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/passing-parameters

Comment: Tried to add some more clarification.  LMK if you still have questions.

Comment: Hi Devin, the tutorial doesn't mention that!! So o have to modify the github Python code for this?